# How to disable easy_install or pip building ppc by default on Snow Leopard 10.6.6?

Tags: mercurial, xcode4, easy-install, pymongo, powerpc

Since I have Xcode 4 installed and it seems xcode 4 can't build ppc binaries anymore, quite a lot of python packages(especially mercurial pymongo, etc.) can't build and complained that there is no "as" installed for ppc architecture. Is there any way to disable pip or easy_install from building ppc?

I have snow leopard 10.6.6, Xcode 4 from Mac App Store. (Xcode 3 is not installed, and I don't want duplicated devtools).

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try setting `ARCHFLAGS`:

```
ARCHFLAGS="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" easy_install mercurial
```

If I just set `x86_64` and then do the easy install, I get:

```
$ file bdiff.so 
bdiff.so: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on my Mac, which has the same setup as the original posters'. Great answer!

Comment: +1 for this. I had the same issue trying to easy_install coverage and this worked perfectly

Comment: I solved this problem by copying ppc/ppc64 "as" from xcode 3.2.6 distribution. But apparently your solution is much better, thanks!